# SQL Server: Are physical operations rolled back after ROLLBACK?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions, rollback

What are the effects of `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` on physical ordering of data in pages? Are physical operations also rolled back when `ROLLBACK` is addressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on these articles by [Paul Randal](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Using-DBCC-PAGE-and-DBCC-IND-to-find-out-if-page-splits-ever-roll-back.aspx) and [SQL Fool](http://sqlfool.com/2009/04/page-splitting-rollbacks/) I'd say "no": on-disk layouts are not rolled back

These are about page splits, but a page split will affect physical ordering of the clustered index (not logical ordering though).

Note: there is never any guaranteed order without an ORDER BY (just in case)

Comment: Thanks for these links, I did a little bit of googling based on links you provided and found this: http://sql.richarddouglas.co.uk/archive/2011/02/rollback-gotchas-%E2%80%93-part-1.html

Comment: Nice link ...slightly wrong about simplicity txns though. When ON a select etc does a silent BEGIN and you have to commit or rollback.